# Youtube FullScreen mode does not work for this HTML code

Tags: html, youtube-api

This HTML code displays an example Youtube video:

```
<HEAD>
</HEAD>
<BODY leftMargin=0 scroll=no topMargin=0>
  <EMBED height="510" width="854" src=http://www.youtube.com/v/9Ky11fJxWBA?version=3&amp;enablejsapi=1 fullscreen="yes">
</BODY>
```

However, when clicking the FullScreen icon on the bottom right-most side of the video in any browser then the video is NOT displayed in full-screen mode. The FullScreen icon simply becomes grayed-out.

So what do I have to change in this HTML code to make the full-screen mode work?

**EDIT:** This **IS** the HTML code of the page. Please try to save this HTML code to a file (e.g. "test.HTML" and then open this file in a browser:

```
<HTML>
  <HEAD>
  </HEAD>
  <BODY leftMargin=0 scroll=no topMargin=0>
    <EMBED height="510" width="854" src=http://www.youtube.com/v/9Ky11fJxWBA?version=3&amp;enablejsapi=1 fullscreen="yes">
  </BODY>
</HTML>
```

**EDIT2:** Please notice that I need to have this work LOCALLY (not from a web server) at least in IE.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/9Ky11fJxWBA?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
fullscreen="yes"
```

Try

```
allowfullscreen
```

Comment: It does not work. The video is displayed but the full-screen icon acts just as before.

Comment: Make sure the url is surrounded by double quotes as well: `<EMBED height="510" width="854" src="http://www.youtube.com/v/9Ky11fJxWBA?version=3&amp;enablejsapi=1" allowfullscreen>`

Comment: From the youtube embed link: `<object width="560" height="315"><param name="movie" value="//www.youtube.com/v/Bb795tWfUBQ?version=3&amp;hl=en_US&amp;rel=0"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="//www.youtube.com/v/Bb795tWfUBQ?version=3&amp;hl=en_US&amp;rel=0" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="560" height="315" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true"></embed></object>`

Comment: What does the rest of your page's html look like?

Comment: The HTML code from the question *IS* the page HTML.

Comment: The code I supplied above seems to work for me. What browser are you using?

Comment: Any browser: Chrome, IE, ... - Have you tried saving the HTML from my question to a file test.html and then opening this file in a browser?

Comment: This worked for me: `<HTML>
  <HEAD>
  </HEAD>
  <BODY>
    <object width="560" height="315"><param name="movie" value="//www.youtube.com/v/Bb795tWfUBQ?version=3&amp;hl=en_US&amp;rel=0"></param‌​><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="//www.youtube.com/v/Bb795tWfUBQ?version=3&amp;hl=en_US&amp;rel=0" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="560" height="315" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true"></embed></object>
  </BODY>
</HTML>`

Comment: I have saved this code locally as "test.html". In Chrome, it does not work neither locally nor from an Internet web-server. In IE, Firefox and Opera it does not work locally, but it does work from an Internet web-server. However, I need this to work locally in IE.

Answer (score 0):

try css style in iframe html5 iframe need to be in line css
ex.

```
style="allowfullscreen:yes; border:none; overflow:hidden;"
```